# Can i factor this expression: $x^3+y^3+z^3$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, divisibility, radicals, fractions

I have the following numerical expression, which is exactly equal to $1$

Text version:

```
(-(7 2^(2/3))/38 + 3^(2/3)/19 + (23 5^(2/3))/95 + (5 6^(1/3))/19 + 3/38 (5^(1/3) 6^(2/3)) - 10^(1/3)/19 - 3/190 (3^(1/3) 10^(2/3)) - (4 15^(1/3))/19 - 6/95 (2^(1/3) 15^(2/3)))*(2^1/3+3^1/3+5^1/3)
```

Image version:

[image]
according to this fact, $x^3+y^3+z^3$ would  be factorized at all and first factor of it should be $x+y+z$ if we set
$
x^3=2,y^3=3,z^3=5
$


If so then how to factor $x^3+y^3+z^3$ ?


**PS.** 
I tried to divide $x^3+y^3+z^3$ by $x+y+z$ and failed (got remainder).

Comment: Do you want to factor this over $\mathbb Z[x,y,z]$ ? If yes, the answer is "$x^3+y^3+z^3$ is irreducible"

Comment: It is not factorizable over $\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]$ by Fermat's last theorem (conjecture? Wiles' theorem? oh well)/.

Comment: Thats true but  how that numerical equality becomes true ?

Comment: The equality deals with non-integers. $x^3+y^3+z^3$ could well be factorizable over $\mathbb{R}$. Could you please explain how that equality implies factorizability of $x^3+y^3+z^3$?

Comment: So seems it can only be factorized in $R$  not in $Z$  right  ?

Comment: If want to do this, just replac $2^{\frac 13}$ with $x$ and $3^{\frac 13}$ with $y$ and $5^{\frac 13}$ with $z$.  But what what be the point?  If $x,y,z$ are fixed then they are not variables.  We are only interested in factoring polynomials if the are variables.  Otherwise you are just finding $(-(7 2^(2/3))/38 + 3^(2/3)/19 + (23 5^(2/3))/95 + (5 6^(1/3))/19 + 3/38 (5^(1/3) 6^(2/3)) - 10^(1/3)/19 - 3/190 (3^(1/3) 10^(2/3)) - (4 15^(1/3))/19 - 6/95 (2^(1/3) 15^(2/3)))*(2^1/3+3^1/3+5^1/3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression can be verified by the following identity:

\begin{align}
  & \; \sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}+\sqrt[3]{c} \\
  = & \:
  \dfrac
   {(a+b+c)^3-27abc}
   {\left(
       \sqrt[3]{a^2}+\sqrt[3]{b^2}+\sqrt[3]{c^2}-
       \sqrt[3]{bc}-\sqrt[3]{ca}-\sqrt[3]{ab} \,
    \right)
    \left[
       (a+b+c)^2+
       3(a+b+c)\sqrt[3]{abc}+
       9\sqrt[3]{a^2 b^2 c^2}
    \right]}
\end{align}

Note that $$(a,b,c)=(2,3,5) \implies (a+b+c)^3-27abc=190$$

Your first factor is just rationalization of the denominator for

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[3]{5}}$$

Comment: This looks amazing. Is there any reference or name for it? Thanks.

Comment: This can be verified by factoring $$(x^3+y^3+z^3)^3-(3xyz)^3$$ where $(x,y,z)=\left( \sqrt[3]{a}, \sqrt[3]{b}, \sqrt[3]{c} \, \right)$

Answer (score 1):

By Eisenstein's criterion and Gauss' lemma, $x^3+y^3+z^3$ is irreducible in $k[x,y,z]$ for any field $k$ not of characteristic $3$. So, for example, it is irreducible in $\mathbb C[x,y,z]$.

Answer (score 0):

You have the identity:

$$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-xz)$$

As far as I know, this is the best you can do, though I'd be happy if someone proves me wrong.

Comment: Sorry but $3xyz$ phase is excess

Comment: this answer is nonsense.